# Словарь или список минимальных значений

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть датафрейм, необходимо сделать список или словарь, чтобы найти участника с минимальным результатом

```
   data = pd.DataFrame({'Score':['result1','result2','result3','result4'],
                    'Василий':[156,198,185,190],
                    'Иван':[170,195,209,211],
                    'Петро':[157,197,129,177]})
```

Вывод должен быть таким:

```
result1:'Василий'
result2:'Иван'
result3:'Василий'
result4:'Петро'
```

Comment: Задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и **укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи**. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: я вообще не могу понять как это сделать, подскажите хотя бы что почитать

Answer (score 1):

Вы указали неверный вывод, если основываться на ваших же данных.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Score':['result1','result2','result3','result4'],
                    'Василий':[156,198,185,190],
                    'Иван':[170,195,209,211],
                    'Петро':[157,197,129,177]})


df.set_index('Score', inplace=True)
print(df.idxmin(axis=1, ))
```

Выведет

```
Score
result1    Василий
result2       Иван
result3      Петро
result4      Петро
dtype: object
```